# Proving of De Morgan's Laws for families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\cal {C} = \{A_i : i ∈ \cal{I}\}$ be a family of sets and let $X$ be another set. Prove the following:
$$X \setminus \bigcup C = \bigcap_{i\in \cal {I}} (X\setminus A_i).$$

Answer (score 1):

What does $A \setminus B$, A take out B, mean by definition? That's your biggest clue.

If $x$ were in the left set, then it must be in $X$ but not the union of the $C$ family. By the simple case of de Morgan, $x$ must be in both $X$ and each $C^c$. The other direction goes similarly.

Comment: @Sean Roberson, would you mind explaining why x  must be in both X and each C^c? I did the same thing for the front, but i have no idea how to continue

Comment: $x \in X \setminus \bigcup C$ means $x \in X \cap \left( \bigcup C \right)^c$, which then means $x \in X \cap \bigcap C^c$. Remember that $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$.

Comment: in this case, your C is referring to the family set right?

Comment: I'm following exactly what you have. Please see the linked duplicate.